# How to make a box rotate and scale in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```css
.box1{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:20%;
  margin-left:-100px;
}

.box1.hover {
  -webkit-animation: moving-image 2s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moving-image {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.3);}
}
```

```html
<div class='box1'></div>
```

When you hover over a box I want it to increase its size and rotate it 360 degrees once. When you remove the cursor from the box I want it to go back to its original shape. I have put my code below and I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
.box1{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:20%;
  margin-left:-100px;
}




@-webkit-keyframes moving-image {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.3);}
}

.box1.hover {
  -webkit-animation: moving-image 2s 1;
}
```

Comment: hover is not a class, don't use single dot, use like this: `.box1:hover`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have what you're looking for: 
There is no need for webkit keyframes & all of that stuff. All I did was add a `:hover` effect and a css transition (which makes the spin effect)

```css
.box1{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:20%;
  margin-left:-100px;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

.box1:hover{
  transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
```

**Edit:**

Your version would've worked fine as well if you change the

```
.box1.hover {
  -webkit-animation: moving-image 2s 1;
}
```

to

```
.box1:hover {
  -webkit-animation: moving-image 2s 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both can be done with transform, like so:

```
    .myClass { 
        transform: scale(1.3) rotate(360deg);
    }
```

but to be on the safe side, you should take care of older browsers:

```
    .myClass { 
            -moz-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(360deg);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(360deg);
            -o-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(360deg);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(360deg);
            transform: scale(1.3) rotate(360deg);
    }
```

The last line should be the standard css3 directive.